# Script not works correct in reindex operation when want to copy particular data from source

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic version is 6.3

Here is the script and try...
Created one 'demo' index

```
PUT demo
{
"mappings": {
"doc":{
"properties": {
"field1":{
"type": "long"
},
"field2":{
"type": "text"
}
}
}
}
}
```

now inserted two documents

```
PUT demo/doc/12_1
{
"field1":12,
"field2":"text1"
}
PUT demo/doc/13_1
{
"field1":13,
"field2":"text2"
}
```

now created one more index demo with same mapping as above

```
PUT demo1
{
"mappings": {
"doc":{
"properties": {
"field1":{
"type": "long"
},
"field2":{
"type": "text"
}
}
}
}
}
```

now i want to copy only 'field2' data into the 'demo1' but my '_id' for new index will be as per 'field1' of the 'demo' and for that i run following script.

```
POST _reindex
{
"source": {
"index": "demo",
"_source":"field2"
},
"dest": {
"index": "demo1"
},
"script": {
"source": "ctx._id = ctx._source['field1']"
}
}
```

but output is

```
"hits": {
"total": 2,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "demo1",
"_type": "doc",
"_id": "G9G_6GgB47Hb5C908ES1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"field2": "text2"
}
},
{
"_index": "demo1",
"_type": "doc",
"_id": "GtG_6GgB47Hb5C908ES1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"field2": "text1"
}
}
]
}
```

here '_id' is randomly generated.
if i remove "_source":"field2", then '_id' is properly generated.

Please suggest something to achieve right behaviour.

Bye and thanks.

Comment: What is the elastic search version?

Comment: 6.3 is the elastic version

Comment: Ok. I answered. Check if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `field1` to `_source` in source index block and then remove it via script after using its value as `_id` for destination.
Use below:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "demo",
    "_source": ["field2", "field1"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "demo1"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._id = ctx._source['field1']; ctx._source.remove('field1');"
  }
}
```

You can also completely ignore `_source` in source block. The below will copy all the fields from `demo` index to `demo1` except `field1`.

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "demo"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "demo1"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._id = ctx._source['field1']; ctx._source.remove('field1');"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks... this ctx._source.remove('field1'); worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the `_source` your only include `field2` from your source index. Do it like this instead:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "demo",
    "_source": ["field1", "field2"]     <--- add field1 here
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "demo1"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._id = ctx._source['field1']; ctx._source.remove('field1')"
  }
}
```

Comment: but then field1 also will get copied which i don't want, only field2 i want

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well yes, after adding _id is properly generated by script, but still is it possible that we can somehow ignore the field1 ?